# Bookmarklet works fine in Opera, but when running in Firefox I get extremely weird results

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I wrote this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:var b = document.createElement("button");b.innerHTML = "Scroll to current video";b.addEventListener("click",() => doItYesly());b.style.position  = "fixed";b.style.left = 0;b.style.top = 0;b.style.zIndex = "99999999";document.body.prepend(b);var s = document.createElement("button");s.style.position  = "fixed";s.style.left = 0;s.style.top = "50px";s.style.zIndex = "99999999";s.innerHTML = "Set";s.addEventListener("click",() => localStorage.setItem("scrolldistanceforosautoscroller",window.scrollY));document.body.prepend(s);function doItYesly(){let inter = setInterval(() => {scrollTo(0,parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scrolldistanceforosautoscroller")));if(window.scrollY === parseInt(localStorage.getItem("scrolldistanceforosautoscroller"))){clearInterval(inter);}},100);}window
```

Basically it's a tiny bookmarklet to allow a user to auto-scroll to a specific point in a long list of videos on YouTube. I wrote it for a friend of mine who repeatedly navigates to the same page over and over, and wanted to try and save some time and prevent from having to manually scroll through all the videos every time he wanted to return to the exact same spot.

When I click this bookmark in my browser (I use Opera) it works just fine. When I open the same bookmark in Firefox (he uses Firefox) it redirects me to a page that says "this page is hosted on your computer" and it simply says `[object Window]`. This is because, in Opera when I would run my code it would print out "input scroll distance", because the last expression evaluated to that. To fix that, I simply pointed to the `window` object, causing the final expression to evaluate to the page itself. This fixed the problem for Opera, but for Firefox it doesn't fix the issue... Instead of just rendering the page like usual, it simply outputs a textual representation of the `window` object...

Is there any way around this? I assume this is for security, and if so then there probably isn't a workaround... But perhaps there's something I could do to make Firefox stop behaving this way?

When I run this same exact code from the dev console it works perfectly as expected, the problem only occurs when I save it as a bookmarklet and click on it. Any ideas?

Comment: `undefined` needs to be the result of the last evaluated statement. This avoids replacing the entire page. Search for [“bookmarklet return value”](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+bookmarklet+return+value) which lists similar questions; I’m sure this is a duplicate of some earlier question. Have you considered writing a userscript instead?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh wow...... I can't believe I never though to try that! Thank you SO much for your comment. If you want to, you can post this as an answer and I'll upvote and mark as accepted. You just saved me so much hassle! I've never heard of a userscript before, I will look into it. Thank you for the suggestion! I just tried out returning `undefined`  and it works perfectly. I love it, and this is hugely helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest wrapping in an IIFE then `void()`... so `javascript:void((()=>{ your code })())`

Comment: @spender Thank you for your comment! I just tested that out, and that works perfectly! I think for now I'll stick with Sebastian's reply, since it just looks cleaner to me and helps prevent parenthesis clutter, but your comment is hugely appreciated as well! Thank you for taking the time to reply.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly bookmarklets were removed from Opera due to "security reasons". In other browsers like Firefox or Chrome, you can use this bookmarklet template to separate the bookmarklet code from the existing JavaScript code:

```
javascript:(function(){CONTENTGOESHERE})();
```

Replace `CONTENTGOESHERE` with your code.